# Apache 2: TemplateSyntaxError: Caught ImportError while rendering: No module named about

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

This is the content of my wsgi file:

```
import os
import sys

# put virtual environment on sys.path
sys.path.append("/check/www/pyapps/lib/python2.7/site-packages")

# put the Django project on sys.path
#sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../../")))
sys.path.append("/check/www/")
sys.path.append("/check/www/textpisodes")

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'textpisodes.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

I created a basic pinax accounts project and I'm trying to make it work with apache and mod_wsgi.But all I'm getting is `TemplateSyntaxError: Caught ImportError while rendering: No module named about`.What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is 'about' an app in our django app settings?

Comment: yes it is.Pinax automatically creates it

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code from my website. Hope to help you!

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, site, sys

# add the virtual environment path
site.addsitedir('/home/admin/webapps/djangotest/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages') # if you are using virtualenv
site.addsitedir('/home/admin/webapps/djangotest/django_project')
site.addsitedir('/home/admin/webapps/djangotest')

# fix markdown.py (and potentially others) using stdout
sys.stdout = sys.stderr

#Calculate the path based on the location of the WSGI script.
project = os.path.dirname(__file__)
workspace = os.path.dirname(project)
sys.path.append(workspace)

os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/tmp'
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'django_project.settings'
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
application = WSGIHandler()
```